# Asynchronous http requests Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

From a certain number of sites (~ 20), I need to collect information (json ~ 100 objects in an array) and after the collection, output it to RecyclerView.

2 options:

1. Make one copy of retrofit for the entire application, and
   synchronously access each site in turn, loading the data into an
   ordinary collection for example
2. Make a copy for each site and collect information asynchronously in
   a thread-safe collection

Do you need asynchrony here? I understand that the volumes are so small. But I'm more worried if the API sites sometimes give a delay, even a small 0.2s, then from 20 sites can drip 1-2s. And this is already very noticeable.

Comment: 1) I believe a retrofit instance is tied to a 'base url', meaning you cannot use the same instance to query multiple websites 2) you cannot execute network requests synchronously, they must always run on a different thread than the main thread

Comment: @TimCastelijns 1) I can, if in the GET\POST methods to specify the full URL, then the "base URL"  is ignored 2) I can execute queries asynchronously from the main thread, but in the same thread for all sites.